# Erro: The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, if, else

Estou escrevendo um código no R porém ele informa o seguinte erro:

> In if ((BWGmax * (1 - exp(-K * (MCisimulate - Xm)))) > WG) { : the
>   condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

Vocês podem me ajudar?

```
BWGmax <- 30
K <- 0.0118
Xm <- 21
SD <- 0.851636356306513
number <- 420
mean <- 28
MCic <- seq(from = 200, to = 270, by = 1.7)
MCisimulate <- rep(MCic, number)

WG <- c()

for(i in 1:number) { WG[i] <- ((sqrt(-2*log(runif(1, 0, 1)))*sin(2*pi*runif(1, 0, 1)))*SD)+(mean)} #mudar depois numeros por parametros
BW <- 0.0223*WG^0.8944
BWG <- if ((BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) > WG) { WG } else {  (BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) }
BWG
```

Answer (score 5):

O `if` no R não é vetorizado, isto é, ele aceita apenas um valor `TRUE` ou `FALSE`. Acontece que na sua linha:

```
BWG <- if ((BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) > WG) { WG } else {  (BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) }
```

O Que está dentro do `if`: `(BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) > WG` retorna um vetor de `TRUES` e `FALSES`.

Neste caso você deve usar a função `ifelse`, que testa a condição especificada, elemento por elemento do vetor. Assim você poderia reescrever esta linha da seguinte maneira:

```
BWG <- ifelse((BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))) > WG, 
              yes = WG, 
              no = (BWGmax*(1-exp(-K*(MCisimulate-Xm)))))
```

A função `ifelse` possui três argumentos:

1. a condição a ser testada em cada elemento do vetor
2. o valor se verdadeiro
3. o valor caso seja falso

Comment: Obrigado Daniel resolveu o meu problema. Abraços!